# PayPal Smart Button onclick Event

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

Currently I am using PayPal smart button for my website's payment gateway and I am using ASP.NET MVC to do so.

I was wondering is it possible to create an "on click" event on the PayPal in the controller. If is possible, how can I do that?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal JavaScript SDK has an 'onClick' function which is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#oninitonclick

Comment: Sorry, I meant is how to detect the PayPal button has been executed as I need to include in the Controller

Comment: Maybe you were looking for information about doing a fetch call to your server, like the sample at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server